# "Incorrect datetime" value no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Olá, estou tentando inserir datas no formato `dd/mm/Y` em dois `jTextField`, no MYSQL, no entanto recebo uma mensagem de erro apenas para o primeiro campo:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '01/01/2016' for function str_to_date
```

O código java é :

```
if (novoCadastro) {
                //Cria a String para inserir os dados
                query = "INSERT INTO Clientes(Nome,Endereço,Cidade,CPF,TelefoneCliente,EmailCliente,Produto,UltimaCompra,ClienteDesde) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(?, '%dd/%mm/%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(?,'%dd/%mm/%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y'))";
            //Seta os valores na String de inserção
           System.out.println(txtUltComp.getText());
           System.out.println(txtClienDesd.getText());
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, txtNome.getText());
            stmt.setString(2, txtEndereco.getText());
            stmt.setString(3, txtCidade.getText());
            stmt.setString(4, txtCPF.getText());
            stmt.setString(5, txtTelefone.getText());
            stmt.setString(6, txtEmail.getText());
            stmt.setString(7, txtProduto.getText());
            stmt.setString(8, txtUltComp.getText());
            stmt.setString(9, txtClienDesd.getText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro realizado com sucesso! ");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme a documentação referente a [formatação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) de datas, um `%d` já representa os dois digitos do dia do mês. Semelhantemente, `%m` já representa os dois digitos referêntes ao mês em si.

Dessa forma, ao invés de

```
STR_TO_DATE(?, '%dd/%mm/%Y')
```

faça

```
STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Ok, mudei para STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%Y') e agora a msg que recebi foi:  Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '01-01-2016' for column 'UltimaCompra' at row 1

Comment: @ClaudioPedra Se as colunas 'UltimaCompra' e 'ClienteDesde' forem datas, você não pode usar DATE_FORMAT na sua query. DATE_FORMAT retorna uma string. É só manter STR_TO_DATE.

Comment: Olá Genos, obrigado pela atenção, mas os dois campos são Strings no java, porém no Mysql estão como date

Comment: @ClaudioPedra como eu disse anteriormente, "Se as colunas 'UltimaCompra' e 'ClienteDesde' forem DATAS[..]". DATE_FORMAT está fazendo você passar uma string para uma coluna date.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, retirei o DATE_FORMAT e funcionou, abraço.

Comment: @ClaudioPedra por gentileza aceite esta resposta caso ela tenha atendido a sua pergunta.